# Azure App Service claims it is running my github bits, it clearly is not

Tags: angular, azure, github

Built the basic Angular starter app with its cli.  Runs locally fine.  Did the ng build --prod to get the runtime.  Pushed that to github. Configured a new Azure App Service running linux with latest version of node. Set the deployment to that github repo.   Azure says it is running from my github, but it is clearly not, it is running its standard "you haven't deployed anything yet" default site.  See the image of what the azure site is showing and the 2nd image of the portal claiming what it should be showing.
I forced the angular to port 80, that did not help.

[image: azure site display]
[image: azure config image]

Comment: don't know why the images are not showing. If you right click them, copy address, and paste in a browser they show. Or you can right click and say "open in another tab" and that works.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your AppService in the Azure portal, it asks for OS.   If you pick windows, then when it asks for run time, if you pick node vxx, it flips the OS to Linux.  and then this fails to deploy from github, per the above.

But, if you pick node vxx, and after it flips the OS to Linux, you click it back to windows  (which does not change the run time)  then deploy pointing to an Angular app in GitHub, it works.

So there is a bug in the Linux side, it fails to create the node/angular run-time correctly.

But it works on a windows host.